# Atom Hydrogen error "unexpected EOF while parsing" for python `if` statement!? (but not other statements)

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, atom-editor, eof, hydrogen

Seems to be a problem w/ how Atom / Hydrogen interprets the code. `for` loops it will give me the option to "fold" or "collapse" by clicking the carrot in the line number. Yet, `if` blocks/statements have no such luck.

Editor name and version: Atom 1.35.1

Platform: Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6

Color scheme: One Dark/Solarized Dark

[image: picture of errors on if:]

```
## this works: 
for i in range(10): 
    print( i)

## this doesn't: 
if not False: 
    print("test worked")

## this example doesn't throw an error, but only executes the "if" and not the else parts: 
x= False
if x == True:
    print("test")
elif x == None:
    print ('test anyway')
else:
    print('test again')
```

I've completely uninstalled atom and deleted all known remaining files (see [enter link description here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-completely-uninstall-atom-for-mac/9084/11), then reinstalled and problem persists.

Comment: if it helps, i pip installed tensorflow, keras, and pip install --upgraded a lot of packages, then this started failing. could that be a problem? seems unrelated, but was the only thing i upgraded in between it working/not working

Comment: "if" is not a loop, but yeah, this may be something funky with atom/hydrogen

Comment: I get these from time to time. Usually it is because I made a change to my code but for some reason the ide doesn't pick up the change and sees an extra indentation where there isn't. Often times I'll copy and past my entire script back in and it fixes itself

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga edited "for loops"

Comment: @EdekiOkoh i've tried that, as well as uninstalling/reinstalling hydrogen, writing new scripts to test it ... it's all of a sudden a consistent problem

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting all the code you want to run before calling the run command.

The other option is to [use cells](https://nteract.gitbooks.io/hydrogen/docs/Usage/GettingStarted.html#hydrogen-run-cell) and the `hydrogen:run-cell` command:

```
# %% Works if you run cells individually with `ctrl+shift+enter`
for i in range(10):
    print( i)

# %% this will now too: 
if not False: 
    print("test worked")

# %%
x= False
if x == True:
    print("test")
elif x == None:
    print ('test anyway')
else:
    print('test again')
```

Unless you select the code you want to run or use cells, Hydrogen tries to figure it out using atom grammar and code folding. Usually it will get it right, but Python indentation and whitespace sometimes throws it off.

Feel free to open an issue if you think this bug should be prioritized, but it may depend on atom apis upstream and the workaround is easy enough I think.

Comment: I agree that selecting a whole code block works correctly in Atom/Hydrogen. Running shift+enter execution on the first line of an `if` is still not working though.

Comment: Yep, I think this is an upstream issue for hydrogen like you suggest.

Comment: Until the [fix is merged in language-python](https://github.com/atom/language-python/pull/300), I'd recommend selecting the block or running as a cell with `ctrl+shift+enter` as in the example. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The folding of `if` statements seems to be a bug in the languages-python plugin, eg., see https://github.com/atom/language-python/pull/300 (they are working on it).

They encouraged me to open a bug issue in hydrogen. Viola: https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen/issues/1589

I believe the solution will be to upgrade once versions are rolled up. This doesn't seem to be a configuration/settings problem at this point.